# In Android is it possible to send sms message to more than one recipient in code?

Tags: android, sms

Using the `smsManager` class can I send the same SMS to multiple numbers at the same time? Or would I need to do some sort of loop?

I want to send the sms from within my app not through the messaging program.

Comment: Did you try sending the numbers separated by commas?

Comment: I tried on the emulator and it didn't work only sends to the first number, let me try on the device and see.

Comment: Ok so separating doesnt work.

Comment: Is it possible to send multiple message to single user[the question below able to send multiple message to single user but the problem is the message sent to 121 contain complete inbox sms as its body not the selected sms body .If possible can someone tell me the problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498002/how-to-send-multiple-sms-to-single-number