# android java sms how to check for error

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I want to check that SMS was sent after:

```
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, smsText, sentPI, null);
```

As I've found as of now the only way is to use a receiver. Am I right?

I've found good example in post:
[Unable to send sms using SMSManager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998655/unable-to-send-sms-using-smsmanager-in-android)
First answer shows how to write a receiver. However, there are comments to that answer, first that more and more receivers get registered with each SMS (I have that), and second how to fix it: unregisterReceiver(this);
I've tried to use unregisterReceiver;
I've changed code in post above to:

```
BroadcastReceiver r = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            unregisterReceiver(r);
```

.....

```
registerReceiver(r, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

It works same as in example. Now I need to add unregisterReceiver(r). 
I've tried to put it after smsManager.sendTextMessage - receiver is not called at all. I've tried to put it in onReceive - was told to declare r as final. So did that, now "r" might not been initiated error.
Where should I put unregisterReceiver to get rid of new and new receivers?

Comment: quick note, in that `onReceive` method,  `unregisterReceiver(r);`  could be `unregisterReceiver(this);` and `r` would not have to be final then.

Answer (score 0):

It started to work fine after change in code @petey commented. Looks like I put `unregisterReceiver(this);` in other place before.