# How to send multiple sms to single number

Tags: android, sms

I want to send multiple SMS by using a checkbox selection. Only selected SMS's content i.e. Their body needs to be send a new message body to #121 which I predefined but the below code, it sends a complete inbox message whether or not I selected no: 121.

Code for main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener{

Button send;
ListView listViewSMS;
Cursor cursor;
SMSListAdapter smsListAdapter;
Context context;
ArrayAdapter<SMSListModel> adapter;
List<SMSListModel> list = new ArrayList<SMSListModel>();
TextView textViewSMSSender, textViewSMSBody;
int i;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    listViewSMS=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSMS);
    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    textViewSMSSender=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSMSSend);
    textViewSMSBody=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSMSBody);
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    smsListAdapter = new SMSListAdapter(this,getModel());
    listViewSMS.setAdapter(smsListAdapter);
    listViewSMS.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.tvSMSSend);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.cbSelect);
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), label.getText().toString()+" "+isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
}

private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.isChecked())
        return "is checked";
    else
        return "is not checked";
}

private List<SMSListModel> getModel() {

    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        for(i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(i)){
                list.add(new SMSListModel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"))));
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   
    if(v == send ){
        mDialog();
    }
    }
       
public void mDialog(){
     // Show The Dialog with Selected SMS 
     AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
     dialog.setTitle("Message Report");
     dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
     dialog.setMessage("Count : "+textViewSMSBody);
     dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ok",
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
         {
             String phoneNo = "121";
             if(list.size()>0){
                 for(i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                     if(list.get(i).isSelected()){
                         
                         try{
                             SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                             StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                             for(SMSListModel p: list){
                                 builder.append(p.toString());
                                 builder.append('\n');
                             }
                            String sms = builder.toString();
                             smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Reported to 121!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }                           
                         catch (Exception e){
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         dialog.dismiss();
                 }
              }
            }
         }
     });
    
     dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS not sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        
                    }
                });
     dialog.show();
        
}}
```

Code for List Modal

```
public class SMSListModel {

private String address;
String body;
private boolean selected;

public SMSListModel(String address, String body) {
    this.address = address;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public String toString(){
    return body;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem with the item click listener

replace your method. I hope it works:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
    TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.tvSMSSend);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.cbSelect);
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
            label.getText().toString() + " " + isCheckedOrNot(checkbox),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    list.get(arg2).setSelected(!list.get(arg2).isSelected());

}
```

Comment: still it send complete inbox messages